# relation has_many rails with inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have :

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, through: :character_items
  has_many :character_item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
class Weapon < Item
class Armor < Item
```

i want to be abble :

myCharacter.weapons

`has_many :weapons, through: :character_items` dont work, i just want the same as items but filter with "type" column to get only weapon objects.

thx for help

PS: i'm on Rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :weapons, through: :character_items, conditions: {character_items: {type: "weapon"}}, class_name: "Item", source: :item
```

hope that helps

**edit**
answer from Matrix:

```
 has_many :weapons, { through: :character_items, source: :item }, -> { where(type: 'Weapon') }
```

Comment: Yes i know conditions possibility, but they dont exist an automatic metod? because if i change the default name value of column who is use to store name Class ("type"), i will have to change all conditions...

Comment: this is a hash you're using here. And key is just a symbol. You'll have to cover it with tests. Also, try to give your columns a clear name so that you don't have to rename them later

Comment: ok, but with Rails 4 its like this: has_many :items, { through: :character_items }, ->(weapons) { where(type: 'Weapon') }

Comment: sorry its: "  has_many :weapons, { through: :character_items, source: :item }, -> { where(type: 'Weapon') }
"

Comment: ok, I'll add it to the answer cause it might help someone else too

Comment: also, since question is resolved either please close it or accept the answer